# Attempting to Create a "Back to Main Menu" button in React.Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have a start button that loads a Game component from the Home component. Im trying to attempt the same concept to return to the home component from the game component. I used conditional (ternary) operator. Here is some code see what I mean.

```
import React from 'react'
import Home from '../Home'

// Class component
class Game extends React.Component {   
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isClicked: false

handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({isClicked: true})
        console.log('what happens', this.setState.isClicked)
      }

 render() {

return (
          <>
            {this.state.isClicked ? <Home /> : <button className = 'home-style' onClick = {this.handleClick}>Return to Menu</button>}
          </>

export default Game
```

Note: what you see above is in the return has more code, but I wanted to display what I attempted. The actual version looks like this:

```
return (
          <>
            {this.state.isClicked ? <Home /> : <button className = 'home-style' onClick = {this.handleClick}>Return to Menu</button>}

          <div className= "buttons">
          <div className= 'score-board'>
            <h2 className= 'play-score'>{this.state.player1.score}</h2>
            <h2 className= 'cpu-score'>{this.state.botPlayer.score}</h2>
          </div>
          <div className= 'results'>
            <h2>{playerMessage} {this.state.botPlayer.choice}</h2>
            <p>{gameMessage}</p>
          </div>
          <div className = 'btn-style'>
            <button className= "for-style1" onClick={() => this.gameRules('rock')}><FontAwesomeIcon className= 'fist' icon={faHandRock} size= '3x' /></button>
            <button className= "for-style2" onClick={() =>this.gameRules('paper')} ><FontAwesomeIcon className= 'knife-hand' icon={faHandPaper} size= '3x' /></button>
            <button className= "for-style3" onClick={() =>this.gameRules('scissors')} ><FontAwesomeIcon className= 'scissor-hand' icon={faHandScissors} size= '3x' /></button>
          </div>
          </div>
          </>
        )
```

The reason why I'm showing this section is because I believe I'm doing something incorrect in the return() section. When I console.log it says undefined. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't make sense to use setstate in your console.log here:

`console.log('what happens', this.setState.isClicked)`

setState is for when you want to tell react that the component and it's children need to be re-rendered with the updated state. you have already done that in the line above (set isClicked to true AND told react to re-render):

`this.setState({isClicked: true})`

So I think you're getting undefined on your console.log because in fact this.setState.isClicked is undefined. I assume that you want to just console.log what isClicked is, correct (i.e. true/false)? Change it to `this.isClicked`.

you didn't really talk about what the problem is though. Is the problem that the button being showed above doesn't work? Does the button display? What's it do when you click it? Walk us through and describe the problem you're having better.

Comment: my apologized Gerald, allow me to explain in detail. I'm attempting to create a button that will onClick a function called handleClick. The idea is this button will take me back to the home page (or Home component). I used a a conditional ternary operator to achieve it. The console.log in the function was just for me to see what is happening.

Comment: i understand all that. but what does or doesn't it do currently? does the button display for you to click on? what happens when you click it?

Comment: when i click it becomes the start button that I use to render the game component, but the game component stays in place and i don't want that.